# How can I assign the Stream type values obtained using Firestore's snapshot() to the State of NotifierProvider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I retrieve data from Firestore using a method like the following:

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetch() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('collection')
      .orderBy('createdAd')
      .limit(10)
      .snapshots();
}
```

I would like to set the Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> type value obtained with this code to the State of NotifierProvider, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: The simplest would be to just wrap the stream in a StreamProvider.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Even when I wrap it with StreamProvider, I'm not sure how to set it to the state of NotifierProvider afterward. Simply writing code to set the stream to the state of NotifierProvider using StreamProvider seems to terminate the process halfway.

Comment: It's a Provider!  You can ref.watch or ref.listen it in any consumer widget or another provider.